# How to use callback function with cocos2d xCode

Tags: objective-c

every one.
I'm making some interesting games.
I thought that, there may be 3 modules, the Main, Actor, target, and other some mod.
The Main module process the main problems, like as the checking end of animation of a sprite.

I want to capture the event in the main module, when the others were ended for their actions.
But, the Main class, it import the other classes, because to give some command to the other classes by calling child object's function.
Then, in the other classes, when the function is ended, they send some complete messages, or call the Main's function. so in the main class, know the end of state that's class, or run the other command.
I couldn't saw any example of that's model.

Are there any ways?

Who can help me?

Comment: Check basic tutorials about obj-c before asking.

Answer (score 2):

Easy, use blocks:

```
-(void) myMethodWithCallback:(void (^)(id)) block 
{
    // something happened here
    block(self);
}
```

And, you can use it like this:

```
[self myMethodWithCallback:^(id sender) {
      NSLog(@"in callback!");
}];
```

Comment: Avoid crashes due to `nil` Block being passed: `if(block) block();`